# Incorrect Signature on Apex Test

Tags: apex

I am getting an Apex error on my test and I am not sure how to solve it
I have tried everyting I could find on different post but with no success which means that there is something that I am still not understanding
Could you please explain me the issue and how to solve it please ?

My error is:
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void updatePropop(Lead) from the type UpdateNumberOfRoom

Code:
UpdateNumberofRoom.apxc:

```
public class UpdateNumberOfRoom {
    
    @InvocableMethod
    public static void updatePropop (List<Id> PropId)
    {
        List <Opportunity_Property__c> propOppList = [
            SELECT id, Property__c, Property_number_of_Keys__c
            FROM Opportunity_Property__c
            WHERE Property__c = :PropId
             ];
        
        for (Opportunity_Property__c currentPropOpp : propOppList) {
            
            Lead CurrentProp = [SELECT Id, Number_of_Keys__c
                                FROM Lead
                                WHERE Id = :PropId
                             ];
            currentPropOpp.Property_number_of_Keys__c = CurrentProp.Number_of_Keys__c;
            update currentPropOpp;
        }
    }

}
```

UpdateNumberOfRoomTest.apxc:

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=false)
public class UpdateNumberOfRoomTest {
    @testSetup
    static void insertFileds(){
      Lead propTest = new Lead(
          LastName = 'Test Property'
      );
      insert propTest;
        
      Opportunity OppTest = new Opportunity ( 
            Name = 'Opportunity 3',
            Description = 'Descriptions 1',
            CloseDate = date.today(),  
            Bottleneck__c = 'bottle 1',
            StageName = 'Early Stage',
            status_picklist__c = 'Pending Analysis', 
            Next_Step_picklist__c = 'Deal Strategy',
            main_related_property__c = propTest.Id
        );
        insert OppTest;
        
       Opportunity_Property__c PropOppTest = new Opportunity_Property__c ( 
            Property__c = propTest.Id,
            Opportunity__c = OppTest.Id
               
        );
        insert OppTest;
    }
    
    @isTest
    static void updateRoomPropOpp()
    {   
        List <Lead> PropList = [SELECT Id FROM Lead LIMIT 1];
        System.Test.startTest();
        UpdateNumberOfRoom.updatePropop(PropList[0]); 
        System.Test.stopTest();
    }    
        
  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you `apex class method` the parameter you are sending is `List of Id` i.e,`updatePropop (List<Id> PropId)`
However, in you `test class` you are sending a `Lead` as a parameter (`UpdateNumberOfRoom.updatePropop(PropList[0]);` ) which is why it is throwing error.

Replace your

```
        System.Test.startTest();
        UpdateNumberOfRoom.updatePropop(PropList[0]); 
        System.Test.stopTest();
```

with

```
System.Test.startTest();
UpdateNumberOfRoom.updatePropop(new List<Id>{PropList[0].Id}); 
System.Test.stopTest();
```

Comment: hi Shagun, thx you for your answer ;) the error is gone but when I run the test I get System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0062600000J4d8EAAR; first error: INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, cannot specify Id in an insert call: [Id] any idea ??

Comment: Check whether you are getting the lead data in List <Lead> PropList = [SELECT Id FROM Lead LIMIT 1];

Comment: Working Great thx you ;)

Comment: Always happy to help :)